# Is there a way to view or store file history (like browser history) in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, command-line-arguments, command-history

Is there any way to "view" (or) "store" file history (similar to browser history). For example if I have 10 files, and I open 2 of them, the following 2 details should get stored in a file:

```
<name-of-file-opened> <date-and-time>
```

This should happen whenever I open a file. So when I open that particular history file, I can see all the files that I have opened (not necessarily edited -- just if I have opened).

I know `lsof` is for viewing the list of all *currently* open files, but is there any way to get a "history".  If there is no in-built command for this, is it possible to create a custom command for the same purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "file history"? What do you need to do to a file that adds it to this history?

Comment: That's for reposting this over here (although I still think the Unix & Linux stack would be a better alternative).  Please remember to delete your [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68442227/11810933) as double-posting is generally frowned on here.  I'll copy my comment from there over here as well -- Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "file history"? Give some examples of the results you'd like to see. Do you mean "see all changes to any file in Linux"? "See the history of when a particular file was changed"? Or what? Thanks!

Comment: @NottheDr01ds Sorry I am new to Stack Exchange. I have edited the question in Unix and Linux stack.

Comment: No worries - We're all new at some point! :-).  I didn't see the "Unix & Linux" one since it wasn't tagged *windows-subsystem-for-linux* there (and that's what I normally look for by default).  Can you confirm that you are using WSL?  That's an important detail for the question as well.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes I am using WSL ..

Comment: Would you consider editing this copy of the question to have the same info as the other one (copy/paste would be fine), since this is the one with answers?  The other one on Unix/Linux could then be deleted.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll also mention `inotifywait` as a possibility for this.  It can typically be found in the `inotify-tools` package (e.g. under Ubuntu, `sudo apt install inotify-tools`).

I'm going to assume that you want to monitor files in a particular directory, since monitoring *everything* would be a bit overwhelming.  Linux is constantly reading and writing files, so you'd quickly have hundreds of entries.  Even monitoring just something like `/etc` would likely be too much, since so many processes need to read information there.

Let's say that you want to monitor everything in `$HOME/projects`, for example.  That could be done with something like:

```
inotifywait -d -o ~/projects-access.log  --format "%w%f %T" --timefmt "%c" -e open "$HOME/projects"
```

That would run `inotifywait`:

- In the background (`-d`)
- Outputting to `~/projects-access.log`
- With the format you asked for in your Unix & Linux question (" ")
- For all files accessed (opened) under `~/projects`

See `man inotifywait` for details.

**Caveat**:  Under WSL, this will only work for files in the ext4 filesystem.  It will not work for files on your NTFS drives (i.e. anything under `/mnt/c`, etc.).  WSL2 does not currently provide support for inotify through the 9P protocol used to access Windows drives from WSL.

I believe the same will hold true for harrymc's answer of `auditctl`, but I have not tested it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does not track file history information.

You will need to configure auditing to track changes to specific files.

Some notes:

- Audit only does future changes
- Auditing a deleted file may cause problem to the daemon.

Look for
[auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl).

Some random references (many more can be found):

- [How To Monitor File Changes Using fswatch In Linux](https://ostechnix.com/monitor-file-changes-using-fswatch-linux/)
- [Monitoring Linux File access, Changes and Data Modifications](http://linux-audit.com/monitoring-linux-file-access-changes-and-modifications/)
- [Track file changes using auditd](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/07/04/track-file-changes-auditd/)
- [The Linux Audit System, or Who Changed That File?](http://www.la-samhna.de/library/audit.html)